# Enumerating results view for data in an SSRS report

Tags: c#, xml

I have to inventory about 400 reports, and what I need to do is pull all the sql out of the reports.  I'm able to XmlDocument load the results and navigate the information in VS and find the information i'm looking for.

In each report I have to click `Results View`

I have to drill down results view for the following Elements.

```
{Element, Name="Report"}
{Element, Name="DataSet"}
{Element, Name="Query"}
{Element, Name="Command Text"}
```

I'm trying to get to the elemental Command Text, but i'm unsure of how to enurmate or access that level.  here is the code i am using:

```
 string[] Fil_Info = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
            foreach (string file in Fil_Info)
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(file);
                //Console.WriteLine(doc.Value.ToString());
                XmlAttributeCollection attrColl =doc.DocumentElement.Attributes;
                foreach (XmlAttribute xmlAtt in attrColl)
                {
                    XmlAttributeCollection attrColl2 = xmlAtt.Attributes;
                    foreach (XmlAttribute xmlAtt2 in attrColl2)
                    {


                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how the XML is structured?  I think you'll want to use LINQ extensions, e.g. `.Descendants(...)`, but I'm not sure exactly how to advise you without more details.

Comment: @TimS. I'm not even sure of how to provide the structure, I do know that at the "Command Text" level the innerxml is what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what you're after and I haven't seen your XML's structure so I'm taking a wild  guess and this is probably not optimal/functional but hey what's the fun if you don't need to tweak it right?

```
IEnumerable<XElement> GetCommandText(string file)
    {
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
    return xdoc.Root.Elements().Where(r => (string)r.Attribute("Name") == "Command Text");
    }
```

if you want more help please, pretty please post a example of what the original XML looks like :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the report server report on the reports. See the forum posts by jcoe on XML Queries at Home » Article Discussions » Article Discussions by Author » Discuss content posted by Michael Davis » Report Server Diagnostic Reports [Page 9](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic859325-2580-9.aspx) and [Page 10](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic859325-2580-10.aspx).

Or to continue with your current approach, here's a Linq query that will parse out what you're after from the rdl file:

```
        XNamespace reportDefinition = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition";
        XNamespace reportDesigner = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner";

        XDocument reportXml = XDocument.Load(@"MyReport.rdl");

        var reportQueries = from XElement dataSetElement in reportXml.Element(reportDefinition + "Report").Element(reportDefinition + "DataSets").Elements(reportDefinition + "DataSet")
                            let dataSetName = dataSetElement.Attribute("Name").Value
                            let queryCommandText = dataSetElement.Element(reportDefinition + "Query").Element(reportDefinition + "CommandText").Value
                            let queryDataSourceName = dataSetElement.Element(reportDefinition + "Query").Element(reportDefinition + "DataSourceName").Value
                            select new { DataSetName = dataSetName, QueryCommandText = queryCommandText, QueryDataSourceName = queryDataSourceName };
```